# What is the concept behind writing a cancel operation in c++?

Tags: c++, functions

I'm attempting to write a cancel operation for a software download application. This application will first transfer the software to the device and then install the software on it. (These are givens I'm not allowed to change).

What should the cancel operation do? When a user presses 'cancel', the application should stop transferring/installing the software immediately.

Question: Since I've never written a "cancel" function, I'm wondering what are the types of things to consider when writing the code, and what are the common bugs I should expect and how to deal with them?

Couldn't find anything in google so if you have some links that would be good reads I'd really appreciate it since I'm not looking for answers I'm just looking for guidelines/macro/concept help

Comment: Cancel is an undo on steroids.  You have to reverse everything your operation did, up to the moment the cancel button was pushed.  That's it.

Comment: I think it's worth clarifying exactly which point in time the "cancel" operation is available. If it's just when you're downloading the application, simply stop the download. But if you are expected to be able to "cancel" something *after* installing the application, then you have a lot more work to do.

Comment: Mazyod's answer is good, but I would add that you should be familiar with multithreaded programming and the weird stuff that can happen with it that does not happen in single-threaded programs.

Answer (score 2):

From a macro perspective, we have the "Installation Transaction". I refer to it as a transaction, since it is a set of ACID operations, kinda.

When the transaction is initiated, you start with the download, into a temporary directory probably. That's the first operation.

After that, you start the installation operation, and that happens mostly by copying files to the appropriate places. You need to modify some other files, probably, you should back those up in your temp directory, as well.

Each task you perform, you can create a [memento for](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern). If the transaction is cancelled, simply go over the memos and roll back everything to restore the user's computer to it's initial state.

The devil is in the details, as well as the language. I don't think I can go any deeper.

Answer (score 0):

> What should the cancel operation do? When a user presses 'cancel', the application should stop transferring/installing the software immediately.

Conceptually, you should consider your installation operation transactionally: each operation is either done or not done (no side effects for a failed operation, no side effects for a partially performed operation).

To do this, isolate as much as possible a change to the system, until it succeeds or fails, and consider committing changes as a transactional step:

Naive approach:

- download software
- install downloaded software
- there is no step 3

Realistic approach:

- split your performed operations as such:

  - operations that cannot fail (commits)
  - operations that can fail (staging)
  - operations that can be undone (rollbacks)
- define the transactional states of your system: connecting to server, downloading, preparing system settings, installing

  - each operation should be performed in the following steps:
  - check preconditions (does not alter system state)
  - stage operation (perform all operations that can fail to get to the next state)
  - commit (set system state based on staged data and state) and set rollback state
  - repeat steps for next operation
- implement each operation to take you from a transactional step to the next, or previous.

Ideally getting to the previous state should not be able to fail, but this is not so in practice. As such, memento is a good pattern to use: enqueue transactional states, and in case you need to rollback, simply state the system to one of the stored states.